# Start docker container on incoming HTTP request

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have a server running multiple web applications inside separate docker containers. I am using [Traefik](http://traefik.io) as a reverse proxy. So, whenever a container is idle for, say 15 mins, I stop the container from inside (end the running process which causes the container to stop). How can I restart the container on demand, i.e., when there is an incoming request for the stopped container?

As asked, I am not using any cluster manager or anything like that. Basically, I have an API server which uses the [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io) library to create images and containers. Traefik listens to the docker events and generates configuration whenever a container is created to route URLs to respective containers.

I tried systemd socket activation. Here are the socket and service files.

**app.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=App Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=3000
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**app@.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=App Service
Requires=app.socket

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start --prefix /path/to/dir
StandardInput=socket
StandardError=journal
TimeoutStopSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my current approach. My containers are running node apps. So, I end the node process inside the containers. While ending the node process, I'll enable and start **app.socket**. And when there is incoming traffic on port 3000, my apps will be started by socket activation.

But nothing happens when I try to access that port. I've confirmed that socket activation is working. When I execute the command `date | netcat 127.0.0.1 3000`, the app seems to start and then immediately stops without any error.

Maybe socket activation doesn't work how I'm expecting it to. I can see that a process `init` with PID `1` is running on port 3000 after enabling **app.socket**. As soon as traffic comes on port 3000, I want to start my node app inside the container. But how can the app start on 3000, if there is already a process running on that port?

Perhaps there's some way to do it with **Traefik** since it is the reverse proxy I am using. Is there some functionality which can allow me to execute a command or script whenever 404 occurs?

Comment: Maybe this issue will help you: https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/6993

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful if you can tell how are you managing your docker containers ( k8 or swarm or anything else ). But based on your initial input, I guess you are looking for Inetd or systemd socket activation. This post can be helpful https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/72sdyf/startrun_a_container_when_incoming_traffic/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look at https://github.com/acouvreur/sablier.

It has Traefik provider.